QwtPlot/QwtPlotCurve with RawSamples: Autoscaling does not work at all
I'm using Qwt 6.3.0 together with QT 6.7.2 to plot some live data with QwtPlot/QwtPlotCurve. At the moment, the data is stored in a fixed size array and gets cyclically overwritten.
In fixed intervals (10ms or something like), I trigger a "replot" on the QwtPlot which should also rescale (=UpdateAxes()) if I'm getting that right from the docs.
Unfortunately, whatever I do, the plot does not autoscale. Data is in Range +-500, the scaling is usually +-1 (which would perfectly match the initial data which is all zero btw.)
If I activate autoscaling some time later when real data is stored in the buffer, it works for the moment but again does not change scaling for new data.
Any ideas what's going on?

Okay, it seems I've found the answer only minutes after posting the question (and after hours of having no clue before ;)):
The problem is QwtPlotCurve::minYValue/maxYValue or the boundingRect respectively. Those are seemingly only updated on calls to "setRawSamples", but not when the underlying data changes or replot is called.
If anyone has a better solution for me (other than changing the underlying data to directly feed it into the QwtPlotCurve), please let me know!

It's quite common to find answers right after posting (o while writing) a question. That specific action results in something similar to what's known as rubber duck debugging (aka, "explain it to your grandma" and other variants). Consider that aspect as a fundamental step in trying to solve your issues and for debugging in general: most of the times we're so used to assumptions we make with the code we wrote that we're not able to understand the bigger (and, often, simpler) picture until we're forced to see it.
